# How to paste the Yanked lines in vim command line after typing other command?

Tags: vim

I wanted to paste the yanked line in the vim command prompt after typing certain command.

I saw a solution where they asked to enter `<Ctrl-R><Shift-">` to paste the yanked lines in the vim command prompt, however I am having the following problems:

1. When I try like, `:tabnew` and then type `<Ctrl-R><Shift-">`, whatever yanked line gets pasted after :tabnew line.
   `Eg: :tabnew /disk/bin/hello.lo`g
2. The above solution doesn't work if I map the same above command in the vimrc. I tried adding the following map in my .vimrc:

   ```
   :map <S-P> :<C-R><S-">
   ```

   When I try `:tabnew` and type `<S-P>`, it is not pasting the yanked line, i.e. the mapped command is not working.

Can anyone help me on the above scenario?

FOLLOW-UP QUERY:

Is it possible to mix normal mode and command line mode operations?

For Eg: 
a. I have a line in text file which is a directory path and wanted to open that directory in vim.

b. Instead of doing Yanking [S-Y] the line and then doing mapped command `[map <C-T><C-O> :tabnew <C-R><S-"><bs><CR>]` to open the directory for vim, is it possible to do something as given below ?

`nnoremap <F7> <S-Y>cnoremap:tabnew <C-R><S-"><bs><CR>`

Please drop you comments/suggestions?

Comment: Could you be more clear about what you want to do, preferably with an exampe? The behavior you describe in 1 sounds like exactly the behavior you say you want in the question.

Comment: @Kevin: True, the behavior in 1, is like I need to type everything like first :tabnew and type enter <Ctrl-R> in keyboard and then type <Shift-"> in the keyboard. But instead of typing <Ctrl-R><Shift-"> in keyboard, I wanted the keys to be mapped in .vimrc as described in 2 - but that's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:` command line prompt is "Command-line-mode" (see `:h Command-line-mode`, `:h cmdline`, or `:h :` [all show the same help]). You can map keys in that mode using `:cnoremap`. So you seem to be looking for this:

```
:cnoremap <s-p> <c-r>"<bs>
```

The backspace at the end removes the trailing end-of-line character that is (probably) at the end of the buffer.

I very strongly suggest you use a different mapping than `<s-p>`, because that will be triggered every time you try to type a capital "P".

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin! This is what I expected!! Appreciate your help!

Comment: Have an added query:
Is it possible to mix normal mode and command line mode operations?

For Eg:
a. I have a line in text file which is a directory path.
b. Instead of doing Yanking [S-Y] the line and then doing <C-R><S-"><bs><CR> to open the directory for vim, is it possible to do something as given below ?
nnoremap <F1> <S-Y>cnoremap:tabnew <C-R><S-"><bs><CR>